# Elementary and interesting examples of Tannakian categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory

I will give a talk to undergraduate about the Tannakian formalism, and I'm looking for an nice example. More precisely I would like an example of a category $\mathcal C$ with a fiber functor $\omega$, giving an equivalence $\mathcal C \cong Rep(G)$ for a finite group $G$ (algebraic group is good too.)

Moreover, I would like that $\mathcal C$ is not too difficult to define.

For example, I know advanced examples (geometric Satake, or quantization of Lie bialgebras, or I think there is something in Tamas Szamuely's book) but they are definitely too advanced.

Comment: The multiplicative algebraic group $G = \mathbb{G}_m$ is usually a favourite, where the corresponding symmetric monoidal category is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces.

Comment: @Joppy : A yes, I think that's a good example ! If you want to make it as answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of Joppy's comment, another nice example is given by the category of local systems on a connected manifold $X$, which is equivalent to $Rep(\pi_1(X,x_0))$. The fiber functor is given by $\omega(\mathcal L) = \mathcal L_{x_0}$  where $x_0 \in X$ is a given base point.